# How To Stop Link Component From Giving 404 Error in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Can anyone tell me why the following Link Component is unable to find the linked page? VSCode is literally auto-completing the file name as I type it in but for some reason I keep getting 404.

```js
//index.js in WelcomePage folder
import styles from "/styles/WelcomePage.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";

function WelcomePage() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>This is the Title</h1>
      <Link href="/pages/ClassSearch">Class Search</Link>
    </>
  );
}

export default WelcomePage;
```

```js
//index.js in ClassSearch folder
function ClassSearch() {
  return <h1>The Class Search Page</h1>;
}

export default ClassSearch;
```

Comment: can you also post an image of your folder structure??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to link `/ClassSearch` instead of `pages/ClassSearch`

If you create `pages/ClassSearch/index.js` that exports a React component ,
 it will be accessible at `/ClassSearch`

```
// <Link href="/pages/ClassSearch">Class Search</Link>
<Link href="/ClassSearch">Class Search</Link>
```

You can check , Next Page Doc

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages

Comment: Realized just after posting, thanks for the link 